# Print odd and even numbers in two threads

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I am learning threads in Python and tried a program to print odd and even numbers in sequence using two separate threads. Below is the program. The program runs correctly but it does not exit. Can someone please point out the mistake I have done?

```
import threading

odd_event = threading.Event()
even_event = threading.Event()


def printEven(n):
    for i in range(0, n, 2):
        print(i)
        odd_event.set()
        even_event.clear()
        even_event.wait()

def printOdd(n):
    odd_event.wait()
    for i in range(1, n, 2):
        print(i)
        even_event.set()
        odd_event.clear()
        odd_event.wait()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = 99
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=printEven, args=(n,))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=printOdd, args=(n,))

    t1.start()
    t2.start()

    t1.join()
    t2.join()
```

Comment: your program deadlocked due to the usage of event

Comment: "_print odd and even numbers in sequence_" - can be interpreted in more than one ways. Can you show an example of the output you're expecting?

Answer (score 2):

### The problem

When I changed your code slightly:

```
def printEven(n):
    for i in range(0, n, 2):
        print(i)
        odd_event.set()
        even_event.clear()
        print("waiting for even event")
        even_event.wait()
    print("printEven finished")

def printOdd(n):
    odd_event.wait()
    for i in range(1, n, 2):
        print(i)
        even_event.set()
        odd_event.clear()
        print("waiting for odd event")
        odd_event.wait()
    print("printOdd finished")
```

This is what I saw:

```
95
waiting for odd event
96
waiting for even event
97
waiting for odd event
98
waiting for even event
printOdd finished
```

What happens is that `printEven` is waiting for an event that will  *never* happen, because `printOdd` has already exited.

### Solution

Add a timeout to the `wait` in the for-loops:

```
import threading

odd_event = threading.Event()
even_event = threading.Event()
TIMEOUT = 0.1


def printEven(n):
    for i in range(0, n, 2):
        print(i, flush=True)
        odd_event.set()
        even_event.clear()
        # print("waiting for even event", flush=True)
        even_event.wait(timeout=TIMEOUT)
    # print("printEven finished", flush=True)


def printOdd(n):
    odd_event.wait()
    for i in range(1, n, 2):
        print(i, flush=True)
        even_event.set()
        odd_event.clear()
        # print("waiting for odd event", flush=True)
        odd_event.wait(timeout=TIMEOUT)
    # print("printOdd finished", flush=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = 99
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=printEven, args=(n,), daemon=False)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=printOdd, args=(n,), daemon=False)

    t1.start()
    t2.start()
```

Of note:

- Added `flush=True` to `print` calls to ensure output buffers are flushed.
- Removed the `join` calls, they are not needed in this case. The main thread is a non-daemon thread, and the new threads inherit this property. According to the documentation:

> The entire Python program exits when no alive non-daemon threads are left.

So when the print threads have exited, the main thread will do so as well.

Answer (score 2):

Adding on @Roland's response, you could also check for when the event isn't supposed to wait so you don't call the wait function when you're not supposed to. For example, with n=99 - though you can adapt the approach for whichever use case you want - the printEven could look like:

```
def printEven(n):
    for i in range(0, n, 2):
        print(i)
        odd_event.set()
        even_event.clear()
        if i != n-1:
            even_event.wait()
        else: # here, we know there won't be any even number to print, so we don't need to wait
            print("don't wait")
```

Comment: I think this check should be added to both printEven and printOdd methods to prevent indefinite wait as n may be even or odd